# Using a curly brace in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to use preg_replace to change the formatting of a TeX file.

This is my code:

```
$regex = "#([\][A-Za-z]+)(Title)#e";
$replace = "('hl\{$1Title}')";
$newphrase = preg_replace($regex,$replace,$newphrase);
```

My problem with is that the "\" before the "{" prints out in my output.

like this:\hl\{FaithTitle} instead of this: \hl{FaithTitle}

I've tried a bunch of different things, here's a couple:

```
$replace = "('hl{$1Title}')";
```

That one crashes the entire page.

```
$replace = "('hl[{]$1Title}')";
```

That one prints out the square and curly braces.

I would appreciate ANY help!

Comment: What's the original phrase? I mean you wrote expected result `\hl{FaithTitle}` but there is missing definition of `$newphrase` in `preg_replace` call.

Comment: There's a lot in the $newphrase variable, but here's part of it: `96, 2005) and  \textit{\FaithTitle} (1977, 1988)
both by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is not doing what you think it's doing.

Because of the `\`, your character class is actually matching `A-Za-z` but also `][` because the `\` escapes the meaning of the `]` and `[` has none inside a class.

Try this:

```
$regex = "#(\\[A-Za-z]+)(Title)#";
```

Also remove the `e` modifier. I don't know why you have it there in the first place, but it's probably why it's crashing.

Comment: `$regex = "#([\\A-Za-z]+)(Title)#";
$replace = "hl{\$1Title}";`

Comment: That's what I ended up with, and it works! 
The `e` modifier was in there from the sample code that I modified...Thanks for the boost!